# Store the "output" to "output"

Tags: php

```
echo '<table border=\'0\' cellpadding=\'0\' cellspacing=\'0\'>';

for ($y=$startY;$y<$startY+$fieldHeight;$y++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($x=$startX;$x<$startX+$fieldWidth;$x++) {
        //echo '(' . $x . ',' . $y . ')';
        echo '<td><img src=\'tiles/' . (isset($map[$x][$y]['terrain']) ? $map[$x][$y]['terrain'] : 'water') . '.png\' alt=\'\' /></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

This data will be updated through jQuery calls. I am just looking for a simple way to store the output from the above in a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Instead of echo-ing, why don't you just store those strings into a variable?

Comment: output buffering seems a better way to go: the code remains unchanged, and it's easy to revert it to the original functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ob_start();
// echo what you want
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Reference for [ob_get_contents();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)

Comment: The $content variable does contain a boolean. How do I echo the actual content?

Comment: sorry it's ob_get_contents();

Answer (score 1):

output buffering:

```
ob_start();
// your code
$data = ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I answered a very similar question just a few days ago.  Why not just assign everything to a variable and then `echo` it?

```
$output = '<table border=\'0\' cellpadding=\'0\' cellspacing=\'0\'>';

for ($y=$startY;$y<$startY+$fieldHeight;$y++) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    for ($x=$startX;$x<$startX+$fieldWidth;$x++) {
        //echo '(' . $x . ',' . $y . ')';
        $output .= '<td><img src=\'tiles/' . (isset($map[$x][$y]['terrain']) ? $map[$x][$y]['terrain'] : 'water') . '.png\' alt=\'\' /></td>';
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}

$output .= '</table>';

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using echo, use either string concatentation, or the output buffering system:

e.g.

```
$var = '<table ....';
for (...) {
   $var .= '<td> ....';
}
$var .= '</table>';
     ^^--- string concatenation shorthand, equivalent to $var = $var . '<table...';
```

or

```
ob_start();
...your code here...
$var = ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: What is most succifient to use?

Comment: I'd recommend using an array and implode() instead of concatenating strings over and over again.

Comment: It would be executed every time a user make a move. so let's say VERY often.

Comment: Then run some benchmarks and see which is easier. a couple string concats will probably be "lighter" than using output buffering or an array/implode sequence, but it's impossible to say where the cutoff point is to switch to the other two options.